# How to clear RememberMe cookie of spring security while logout in Grails

Tags: spring, grails

Iam using spring-security-core 2.0-RC5 in my grails application (2.4.4). I clicked Remember Me check box and logged in. But the problem is I cannot logout now. When calling logout controller nothing happens.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to clear the cookie from your browser??

Comment: Are you using the default controller? Have you overridden any of the plugin's files?

Comment: Ya I'm using CustomSessionLogoutHandler which implements LogoutHandler

Comment: When I clear my browser cookies then only am able to logout.

Comment: String cookieName = "SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE";
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
  cookie.setMaxAge(0);
  cookie.setPath(StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContextPath()) ? request.getContextPath() : "/");
  response.addCookie(cookie);

Comment: I tried the above code in my void logout method CustomSessionLogoutHandler  but the problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this problem.

I just added rememberMeServices in the handler 
names of my Config.groovy like follows

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = ['customSessionLogoutHandler','rememberMeServices','securityContextLogoutHandler']
```